# Android Webview error code -6

Tags: android, webview

Hi everyone I am having an issue with an android webview : The webview works fine until I try to redirect to specific url ( which coincidentally happen to ask for cookies) "net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" is the error description and "-6" is the error code. Can anyone assist with how to fix this ? If I use the device browser it is  working fine but with webview I get an error:

```
**My webview client**

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.content.Intent;

public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{

    Context context;
    TransactionHandler handler;

    public MyWebViewClient (Context c, TransactionHandler handler){
        this.context = c;
        this.handler=handler;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.i("WebView", "Url is " + url);

        if (url.contains(ApiConstants.payFailUrl)) {
            handler.onFailed();
            return false;
        }
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().contains(ApiConstants.payUrl)) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            return false;
        }
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().contains("the url i want to go to(should be here) which is triggering an error(i think it has something to do with them using cookies")) {


            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
//            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
//            context.startActivity(intent);
            //view.loadUrl(url);
//            view.loadUrl("https://www.google.com.gh/");
//            return true;
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
//        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
//        context.startActivity(intent);
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.i("WebView", "pageFinished Url is " + url);

        if (url.contains(ApiConstants.paySuccessUrl)) {
            handler.onSuccess();
        }

        if (url.contains(ApiConstants.payUrlbeta)&&!url.contains("data:")) {
            handler.onSuccess();
        }
        if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(context)&&!url.contains("blank")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "wrong " + url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Utils.showAlert(context, "Please check your internet connection", "No Internet");
            view.loadUrl("about:blank");

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);

        if (view.canGoBack()) {
            view.goBack();
        }
        else{
            view.loadUrl("about:blank");
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "" + error.getErrorCode(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Paul. Welcome to posting on Stack Overflow. Can you please post the relevant parts of your code. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: post was updated

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I also have a similar issue but that happens intermittently.