# Android : webview : getting error code -6 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: android, webview

I keep getting errorcode -6 and description net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on android webview in

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final WebView webview =(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());//I only implemented onReceivedError to display the errors in logcat

    webview.loadUrl("http://mydomainexample.com");// it loads http://google.com but throws error code = -6 for my doamin which works fine in any navigator

}
```

while the exact same url (example http://aaaaaaaaa.com) works well in any navigator, do webviews make connections differently from navigators?
 What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Post ss of your webview results

Comment: ´http://´google.com will auto-redirect to **https**://google.com. What Android version are testing on? The issue might be SSL-related, also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie)

Comment: I'm testing on android 8.1.0

Comment: I've the proposed solution(adding usesCleartextTraffic) it still gives me the same error

Comment: Could it be an issue on the server side? the ports 80 and 8080 have been allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the loaded webpage had a js file that, asynchronously, made a request to a port which was blocked on the server. I've tried removing that request and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Maybe due to cookie request by the website (see [Android Webview error code -6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51518347/android-webview-error-code-6)) but please post your code.  There is also a posting on https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1848

Comment: I don't use cookies, I didn't see any solution to this in the url https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1848